# Tornado does not check if Javascript files are updated without updating index

Tags: python, tornado, http-caching

I'm using Tornado to serve and HTTP file that uses multiple JavaScript files like this:

```
<script src="static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="static/js/stream.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="static/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/d3.slider.js"></script>
```

Unfortunately, when I change these files, it doesn't realize that they've changed and continues to respond with `304` responses. I tried stopping these responses by disabling caching, but that didn't work.

Is there some other setting I'm supposed to be setting in Tornado? Is this a bug I should report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RequestHandler.static_url`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.static_url). It will return a versioned url (by default appending ?v=), which allows the static files to be cached indefinitely.

Steps to enable it:

1. Define `static_path` in your settings, it is directory from which static files will be served:

   ```
   settings = {
       'static_path': '/var/www/static/',
       # other settings
   }
   ```
2. Provide this settings to your application:

   ```
   app = tornado.web.Application(settings=settings, **kwargs)
   ```
3. Use `static_url` in templates:

   ```
   <script src="{{ static_url('js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{{ static_url('js/stream.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="{{ static_url('js/d3.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ static_url('js/d3.slider.js') }}"></script
   ```

The output will be something like (check those `?v=hash`)

```
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js?v=12d" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/stream.js?v=34a" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/d3.min.js?v=df3"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/d3.slider.js?v=ad1"></script
```

Comment: Yes, they're generated automatically by a hash of the content.